# How to dynamic_cast in objective c

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-cast

I'd like to write this code on objective c:

```
    bool BordVertical::collisionwith( Jeu& jeu, ElementJeu& element )
{
    // Verify if the element is balle ype
    Balle* balle = dynamic_cast<Balle*>( &element ) ;
    if( balle )
    {
        balle->Vx( -balle->Vx() ) ;
        return true ;
    }
    return false ;
}
```

ball is a subclass of ElementJeu...
Does anything similar exist in obj-c?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need it. Objective-C knows the type of your objects.

```
- (BOOL) collisionwith:(ElementJeu*)element {
    if ([element isKindOfClass:[Balle class]]) {
        [element setVx:[element getVx]];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

PS: `jeu` is redundant.

Comment: generally the setter/getter pair would be setVx: and vx not getVx